# get the video file after convert from base64 and UTF8 in c#

Tags: c#, java, base64, fileinputstream

what i need to do is sending a file from java to c#. the java act as the client meanwhile, c# act as server.

the file is loaded in java through fileinputstream and its been converted to utf8 then base64. see the code.

```
FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(fileName);
          byte[] content = new byte[fin.available()];
          fin.read(content, 0, content.length);
          String asString = new String(content, "UTF8");
          byte[] newBytes = asString.getBytes("UTF8");
          String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(newBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and the server (using c# language) will read the data send and convert it back as a file. im using base64 then to utf8 and last i am not sure how to make it. what im trying to send is video.mp4 size of 144kb or less. so far, the output shows the catch of "WRONG FORMAT". see the code.

```
    try
            {

                for (int i = 0; i <= _server.Q.NoOfItem - 1; i++)
                {
                    words = _server.Q.ElementAtBuffer(i).ToString();
                    //textBox1.Text = words;


                    byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(words);
                    string returnValue = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes);

                    textBox1.Text = returnValue;

                }
}
            catch (ArgumentNullException argNull) 
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Received null value";
            }
            catch (FormatException FrmtEx)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Wrong format";
            }
```

you can ignore the `for (int i = 0; i <= _server.Q.NoOfItem - 1; i++)` as this is the way i want to capture/retrieve the data sent.

p/s: it works when im just trying to pass any string without load the file (string >> utf8 >> base64) and to receive (base64 >> utf8 >> string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the file is loaded in java through fileinputstream and its been converted to utf8

Then you've lost data. Video data is *not* text data, so don't load it as text data. Treat it as binary data - by all means encode it to base64 if you need to represent it as a string somewhere but *don't* perform any text decoding on it, as that's only meant for *encoded text data*, which this isn't.

It's *really* important to understand what's wrong here. The *only* thing the two lines below can do is lose data. If they don't lose data, they serve no purpose - and if they *do* lose data, they're clearly a bad idea:

```
String asString = new String(content, "UTF8");
byte[] newBytes = asString.getBytes("UTF8");
```

You should analyze how you ended up with this code in the first place... why did you feel the need to convert the byte array to a string and back?

jowierun's answer is *also* correct - you shouldn't be using `available()` at all. You might want to use utility methods from [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), such as [`Files.toByteArray`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#toByteArray%28java.io.File%29) if you definitely need to read the whole file into memory in one go.

> p/s: it works when im just trying to pass any string without load the file (string >> utf8 >> base64) and to receive (base64 >> utf8 >> string).

Well yes - if you *start* with text data, then that's fine - UTF-8 can represent every valid string, and base64 is lossless, so you're fine. (Admittedly you could break it by presenting an invalid string with half of a surrogate pair, but...) The problem is at the point where you treat non-text data as text in the first place.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. now im trying to use this method. fileInputStream >> create byte >>  read the bytes using offset. do you think i should use base64 or i shouldn't? what's with the base64, anyway?i thought of doing the base64 to convert would make the process much easier but using the offset, i think its enough. i dont know.that is only my perception. im still new to this thing

Comment: @sarabrown: We don't know enough about your transport requirements. If you *have* to use a string to transport the data around, then use base64. If you can just pass the binary data *as* binary data, do so.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `fin.available()` to assume you can read the file in one go.  That is likely to work for only small files.  Instead you need to do the read in a loop and collect all the contents together before you encode it.

It would make sense to (on the java side at least) to have a decode that routine you can use to TEST that your encode is working (a unit test perhaps?).  You will probably find that test is failing consistently with the problem you are getting.